# Supervised Learning(Classification) with unique labels

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, decision-tree

I have some dataset that is all categorical data, with unique labels.
Something like this:

```
X =

1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0

1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1

0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1

.

.

.

1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1

y = 

AA

AB

AC

.

.

.

ZZ
```

I believe this problem should be solved something other than machine learning, but my boss is forcing me to use machine learning or deep learning algorithm.

So my question is:

1. What would be the best Non-Machine-Learning algorihtm to solve this?
2. What would be the best Machine Learning algorithm to solve this?

Comment: In your response variable `y`, is every value really unique?

Comment: How many lines of data do you have? If the total values are (26*26) then its of no use. Without the actual data we cant say anything.

Answer (score 0):

As a classification problem it has no meaning. You have to have many rows with same labels to deduce something from data by any classification algorithm.
I can propose to turn this problem to regression by converting labels to unique numbers (using numbers of letters in alphabet or something like this). Then you can use any regression algorithm to assume numbers of unlabeled data. And finally you can turn these numbers back to text labels. I'm not sure this will work, but you can try.

```
AA -> 0
AB -> 1
...
AZ -> 25
BA -> 1 * 26 + 0 = 26
...
ZZ -> 26 * 25 + 25
```

Comment: Thanks. But in this way, the data is ordered, which we do not want in categorized data.